# JQuery form update listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trigger a javascript function when one of the elements in a specific form has been changed. Is this possible using jquery?

Does anybody has an example how to do this?

Comment: A `-1` 4 years after having asked the question? But why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function () { 
  $('form#id input[name=joe]').change( function() { alert('it changed!'); });
} );
```

Comment: thanks... didn't know it was that simple... just calling the change event on the form.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a text field like this:

```
<input type='text' id='myInput'>
```

You can do this:

```
function executeOnChange() {
    alert('new value = ' + $(this).val());    
}
$(function() { // wait for DOM to be ready before trying to bind...
    $('#myInput').change(executeOnChange);
});
```

[Here is an example of this in action](http://jsbin.com/ilupa).

Please note you have to lose focus on the text field in order for the `change` event to fire.

If you want to select the input by name instead of ID, you can change `$('#myInput')` to `$('input[name=myName]')`. For more on selectors, [check out the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors).

Answer (score 2):

Jut write a selector for the items in the form and attach a change handler
see
http://docs.jquery.com/Events/change#examples